# No Google audio captchas via Tor?

Tags: google, captcha

Sometimes, [when Google’s new captchas annoy me when using Tor](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/17974/22877), I would like to use Google’s audio captchas as an alternative. But as soon as I click on the headphone symbol in order to listen to an audio captcha, I get this **every time**:

[image]

Am I the only one or is it impossible to solve Google audio captchas when using Tor?

Comment: Yes, it's impossible to solve *any* types of reCAPTCHA captchas via Tor. Audio captchas never start (the message as on your screenshot appears) and visual captchas are unsolvable no matter whether you provide correct or incorrect answers. This is based on my experience, I've got no sources to quote, so I'm not writing this as an answer.

Comment: @izogfif Well, solving reCAPTCHA’s is not completely impossible but very annoying because you need [**a lot** of tries until your answer will be accepted](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/17974/22877). This is, at least, true for non-audio captchas.